# How to set up birthdays with org-contacts? Error: Bad sexp

Tags: emacs, org-mode

How can I set up anniversaries with org-contacts so that birthdays etc. are shown in my agenda.org file?

My agenda.org file contains the following, as mentioned on the bottom of [org-contacts](https://julien.danjou.info/projects/emacs-packages#org-contacts)

```
#+STARTUP: showeverything
* Birthdays
  %%(org-contacts-anniversaries)
```

My contacts.org file contains (e.g.):

```
* My contact                                                   :my.tag:
:PROPERTIES:
:EMAIL:  address@hidden
:URL:
:WORK: 
:HOME: 
:MOBILE:
:LOCATION:
:BIRTHDAY: 2000-01-01
:NOTE: 
:END:
```

When I access agenda view via C-c a a, I obtain:

Bad sexp at line 3 in /Users/myusername/org/agenda.org: 
(org-contacts-anniversaries) [7 times]

Note that line three corresponds to "%%(org-contacts-anniversaries)"

I tried to contact the author of org-contacts but did not obtain an answer (so far). I am hoping someone has tried this before and it worked. I tried it under Emacs 24.0.91 (9.0) on Mac OS X 10.7.2

Comment: I can confirm it does work. I'm using it on Emacs 24.0.50.1 which I believe was one of the latest patched versions for W32. I also have it working on a more recent version from BZR on Archlinux. In both cases with the current git version of Org (over the last 3 months or so)

Comment: I did however have a temporary issue about 1 - 1.5 weeks ago where `%%(org-class ...)` entries were giving bad sexp errors. Pulling from GIT then reloading org (or outright closing and re-opening Emacs) got rid of the issue, so it may have been a temporary sexp issue that affected this as well.

Comment: okay, that's "good" to hear (that someone else had trouble here, too). Although I have the latest version of org-mode (7.7; coming with org-contacts), I'll try to compare the development version or org-contacts with the one I have later today and get back to you.

Comment: The development version (latest snapshot) is precisely the same as the one I have...

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem by changing the org-contacts-files variable to a list rather than a string.

For example, going from:

```
(setq org-contacts-files "~/Org Files/contacts.org")
```

to:

```
(setq org-contacts-files '("~/Org Files/contacts.org"))
```

worked for me.

It looks like the `org-contacts-filter` function expects the `org-contacts-files` variable to be a list rather than a string.

Answer (score 3):

I got the error when there are contacts with the BIRTHDAY property but no value. Removing these entries eliminated the error.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the two first blank spaces at the beginning of the line "%%(org-contacts-anniversaries)"

```
#+STARTUP: showeverything
* Birthdays
%%(org-contacts-anniversaries)
```

Comment: This is not possible since I have 
    (setq org-startup-indented 1);
in my .emacs (I like the indentation) Or do you know how to achieve it anyway?

Comment: The strange thing is, even without org-startup-indented, I get the * and ** headings indented. Hmmm...

Comment: Okay, I found #+STARTUP: noindent, but even with that, I obtained indented sections...

Comment: Okay, I could start emacs from the command line (not the GUI version) which then started without indentation. I get the same error "bad sexp..."

Comment: Try opening the file in a non-emacs editor just to confirm whether the %%( line has the spaces at the start or not. If you manually tabbed at any point in time they will be indented regardless of the #+STARTUP: value.

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan. I manually moved (in a different editor, the "%%(org-contacts-anniversaries)" line to the left, then opened it in emacs: I obtained the same error. This is strange... especially the fact that I set the indent to 0 (or nil) and it is still indented on startup [even after a complete restart]. But as I wrote above, starting emacs from the command line I could try it out with the %%-line moved to the left and it still does not work.

Comment: Though I'm sure no indent and `org-contacts` loaded successfully, I still get this error on Windows. The same file is OK under Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you don't have any dates before 1970 for birthdays. This is an issue with Unix Time that has been discussed on the mailing list [1](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/42139/focus=48857). I don't know what would need to be changed for this to be fixed in 32-bit Emacs, however it appears that it should work in the 64-bit versions (I don't have access to a 64-bit version to test right now).

Comment: Hi, how can I determined whether my emacs version is 32 or 64bit? (My OS is 64bit)

Comment: @MariusHofert I would suspect you're in 32-bit due to the fact you're receiving the error. However M-x emacs-version should give some indication (on my Windows machine it states: GNU Emacs 24.0.50.1 (i386-mingw-nt5.1.2600) from trunk 2011-02-16 on LENNART-69DE564 (patched). Unless you compiled it yourself it most likely would be 32-bit. The other way to be sure would be to look at where you downloaded it from, if it doesn't state 64-bit it should be 32-bit.

Comment: GNU Emacs 24.0.91.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin, NS apple-appkit-1038.35) of 2011-10-31 on virtualmac.porkrind.org
I wanted to compile it myself, but it did not work so I used the very latest build (s. pretests) from http://emacsformacosx.com/builds

Comment: @MariusHofert The method to test to see if it would work would be to try to insert a timestamp <1970 or >2038. For example `C-c ! 2060` for me tries to insert `2037-11-08`, and `C-c ! 1910` defaults back to `1970-11-08`. If it does the same for you (Or defaults back to 2011 in both cases) emacs+your system cannot properly represent dates <1970-01-01 and >2037-12-31. You'll simply have to adjust your birthdates to fall within the compatible time unfortunately. (At least until Emacs+OS is able to properly represent those dates).

Comment: Okay, we come closer...:
1) I removed *all* birthday dates from contacts.org and I still obtain the same "Bad sexp..." error. 
2) I put in a new date in agenda.org with C-c . I had to flip through the months till 2039 but when I hit RET, I saw: "Year was forced into compatible range (1970-2037)" and indeed <2037-03-01 Sun> was inserted
Okay, so this might indeed be a problem. BUT: Why do I get this error even if there are no birthday dates at all?
=> It seems that empty :BIRTHDAY: tags also cause the problem. And indeed, removing them and hitting C-c a a finally worked without problems...

Comment: Also, putting in a birthday in the range worked as well! Okay, so the only pitty is that years < 1970 can not be used. I assume this is an emacs problem since the Mac is 64bit.

Well, thanks a lot for your help, Jonathan!

Comment: @MariusHofert I'm not sure I'd qualify it as an Emacs problem as such based on the discussion in the thread I linked (and the one it links to). It has to do with how Emacs retrieves the date from time_t in linux (Windows uses a different method to determine time, which Emacs converts internally as well). OSX may have it's own implementation that is also not compatible with Emacs with regards to 64-bit time representation.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the cause of this issue was a mixed Org-mode install. From the Org-mode FAQ: (http://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html#mixed-install):

> Emacs is distributed with a version of Orgmode bundled with it. A common problem among users who install a newer version of Orgmode separately is a mixed install where Emacs loads some files from the bundled and the rest from the latest version. This can lead to unending troubles in the future. With a recent installation of Org mode M-x org-version will indicate if the installation is mixed.
>
> With somewhat older Org mode installations, the procedure is more involved and indeterminate. An easy first step is to look at the output of M-x org-version.
>
> Good
>       Org-mode version 7.8.11 (release_7.8.11-448-g1737d3 @ /path/to/org-mode/lisp/) 
>   Bad
>       Org-mode version 6.33x (release_7.8.11.409.ga3778)
>
> A second step is to go through the output of list-load-path-shadows line-by-line to get hints to what in your configuration is causing the issue. Among the most common reasons is Orgmode gets loaded before the load-path variable is updated to include the installation directory of the latest Orgmode. To avoid issues like this, it is recommended that the load path is updated very early on in your init file.

P.S. the error I was having when M-:

```
(org-contacts-anniversaries)
```

was:

```
void-function org-with-buffer-modified-unmodified
```